# gtk composite widget focus

Tags: c, gtk

I created a composite widget with webkit_webview widget stored in scrollwed window with a gtkvbox base widget. How do make to so the base gtkvbox widget is in focus whenever any of the contained widgets have focus? Specifically, I am trying to add accelerator that should only be active when the composite widget is in focus. To determine if the composite widget is in focus I call gtk_widget_get_focused(), and then traverse up the widget parents to to the fill find the base widget . It seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one widget at a time can have the global input focus, which is the focus that the user sees on the screen, and where the keystrokes appear. If `gtk_widget_has_focus(widget)` returns `TRUE` then `widget` has the global input focus. You can't have the webview and the vbox have the global input focus at the same time.

What you can do is call `gtk_container_get_focus_child()` on the composite widget's parent, and if the return value is your composite widget, then the focus is somewhere within the composite widget.

Or you can connect to the `"focus-in-event"` and `"focus-out-event"` signals on the composite widget. I'm fairly sure these will notify you when one of the contained widgets gains or loses the focus. (Remember to call `gdk_window_set_events(widget->window, gdk_window_get_events(widget->window) | GDK_FOCUS_CHANGE_MASK)` on your widget first, as explained in the GTK docs.)